# What's the difference between performSelectorOnMainThread: and dispatch_async() on main queue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I was having problems modifying a view inside a thread. I tried to add a subview but it took around 6 or more seconds to display. I finally got it working, but I don't know how exactly. So I was wondering why it worked and what's the difference between the following methods:

1. This worked -added the view instantly:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //some UI methods ej
    [view addSubview: otherView];
}
```

2. This took around 6 or more seconds to display:

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodThatAddsSubview:) withObject:otherView
    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

3. `NSNotification` methods -  took also around 6 seconds to display the observer was in the viewController I wanted to modify paired to a method to add a subview.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
 @"notification-identifier" object:object];
```

For reference these were called inside this `CompletionHandler` of the class `ACAccountStore`.

```
accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // my methods were here
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that `performSelectorOnMainThread:` didn't work, how did it fail? Did you get an error message? Was it a runtime error a compilation error? If you didn't get an error, how do you know that it failed?

Comment: Is `addSubview:` the only method you used that touched UI elements, or are there others as well?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I forgot to mention that it worked but it took around 6 or more seconds to display.

Comment: @MattWilding Yes it was. During my testing I tried to add a blank subview and still took around 6 seconds to display with the nsnotification and performselector on main thread.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

By default, `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` only schedules the selector to run in the default run loop mode. If the run loop is in another mode (e.g. the tracking mode), it won't run until the run loop switches back to the default mode. You can get around this with the variant `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:` (by passing all the modes you want it to run in).

On the other hand, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... })` will run the block as soon as the main run loop returns control flow back to the event loop. It doesn't care about modes. So if you don't want to care about modes either, `dispatch_async()` may be the better way to go.

Comment: What are modes, and when should I care about them?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: On iOS, you can basically ignore them, the runloop typically always runs in the Default mode. On OS X there are 3 more modes that you may see, `NSConnectionReplyMode`, `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`, and `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`. You can look up the docs for those if you're interested.

Comment: Note that in iOS UITrackingRunLoopMode is used for certain touch event tracking (when a UIScrollView is tracking a touch movement).

Comment: That's not true that it uses the default run loop mode. performSelectorOnMainThread is documented thusly: *"This method queues the message on the run loop of the main thread using the* ***common run loop modes*** — *that is, the modes associated with the* ***NSRunLoopCommonModes*** *constant."*

Comment: If you start a model dialog window within a main-thread dispatch_async block, on OS 10.9 scrolling via mouse wheel won't work (presumably b/c that only works in the default runloop mode). Also, uncaught exceptions will always terminate the program, which is bad in production code (only way out would be to nest a try-catch within each dispatch_async-block you write). For these reasons, we prefer performSelectorOnMainThread. We created a dispatch_async_main variant that internally calls performSelectorOnMainThread, so we can keep using the nice block syntax.

Comment: @AndreasZollmann "uncaught exceptions will always terminate the program, which is bad in production code" GCD explicitly documents that you should never let an exception get thrown out of your block and into GCD. Also, I *very strongly* disagree with the "is bad in production code". *Ignoring exceptions* is bad in production code. This is why iOS made the choice to abort on an uncaught exception, instead of the log-and-ignore approach of OS X.

Comment: Killing the app is usually worse for the user than letting the show go on. We catch exceptions in the main runloop of the program, show a dialog to the user that something "the programmers did not foresee" has happened, send the stacktrace to our server and continue the program. Of course we don't ignore them but analyze them and fix the bugs for future releases. Most of the time it's stuff of no  consequence to the user like pre-selecting the last entry of a table and forgetting to handle the case where the underlying array is empty.

Comment: @AndreasZollmann: An uncaught exception can mean that all bets are off for the rest of the program. Not only could invariants in your data structures no longer hold, but it's also considered undefined behavior to throw an exception through Cocoa framework code (the frameworks do not make any attempt to maintain invariants themselves in the face of exceptions). This is basically like a less-risky memory corruption. For all you know, you're about to overwrite the user's document with garbage data because of an uncaught exception.

Comment: Sorry for letting myself in, but do you have any clue as to why I was encountering the opposite behaviour? I was trying to `dispatch_async` on the main queue a `setNeedsDisplay`, but that was taking a fair amount of time to show a picture; so I put the whole method inside `performSelectorOnMainThread` and it finally worked as expected. The call is inside the `completionHandler` of a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, and I guess that's part of the problem, but why?

Comment: I can't use performSelectorOnMainThread in swift... And I need to wait for the UI operation to finish, so I won't get a " deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction"... is dispatch_sync the only solution? Ignoring all run loop modes?

Comment: @AxelZehden `dispatch_async()` is the most common way to handle this in Swift. A block dispatched that way should run in all "common" modes.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` queues the message with common run loop modes. According to [Apple's *Concurrency Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), the main queue will interleave queued tasks with other events from the app's run loop. Thus, if there are other events to be processed in the event queue, the queued blocks in the dispatch queue may be run first, even though they were submitted later.

[This article](https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/11/performselectoronmainthread-vs-dispatch-async.html) is a superb explanation to `performSelectorOnMainThread` vs. `dispatch_async`, which also answers the above question.

Comment: FYI, the article is not accessible anymore

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the`PerformSelectorOnMainThread` with `waitUntilDone=YES`

Eg:

**Code:**

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodThatAddsSubview:) withObject:otherView waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I think that might solve the issue as of why the `PerformSelectorOnMainThread` takes so long to respond.