# Block version of performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, event-handling, objective-c-blocks

Is there a way that I can execute a block rather than a selector corresponding to this and similar methods?

I have observers that may receive events that aren't generated on the main thread. I want the action to be performed on the main thread if it is primarily UI oriented. Right now, I need to write two methods to do this, where one is the event observer, and the second is the code that needs to be executed on the main thread.

I would like to encapsulate this all into one method, if I could.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The preferable technology for block-supporting multhreading actions is called Grand Central Dispatch. You can find some sample code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch#Examples) and in the [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        //background tasks

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //tasks on main thread
        });    
});
```

Comment: It seems these two are not equivalent according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335434/whats-the-difference-between-performselectoronmainthread-and-dispatch-async-on-m). Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544207/how-to-avoid-coreanimation-warning-deleted-thread-with-uncommitted-catransactio) for a more UI-specific answer.

Answer (score 13):

[GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) should do the trick:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do stuff here
});
```

Or `dispatch_async` if you were planning on `waitUntilDone:NO`. The [main queue is guaranteed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/macro/dispatch_get_main_queue) to be running on the main thread, so it is safe for UI operations.

Comment: I swear I've answered this before, but I can't find the duplicate. /me shrugs

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Josh. This is the answer I have seen, which I will implement. Since both answers are tagged with the same time, I will give Fscheidl the green check, and give you an up vote. I hope you don't 'mind.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've got more rep than I know what to do with, so no, it doesn't matter, thanks.

Comment: "dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)" freezes the UI. Any suggestion?

Comment: @x4h1d Calling it from the main thread? That way you create a deadlock.