# animated circle on map with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, mkoverlay, mkmapview, catransaction

I am using YHAnimatedCircleView (http://yickhong-ios.blogspot.it/2012/04/animated-circle-on-mkmapview.html) to display an animated circle on a map. It works well with iOS6, while I am experiencing some problems with iOS7.

The circle appears after a long period on the map and it returns me the following error:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;

0   QuartzCore                          0x00fcfa96 _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 374
1   QuartzCore                          0x00fcfe72 _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 316
2   QuartzCore                          0x0106791b _ZN2CA5Layer12begin_changeEPNS_11TransactionEjRP11objc_object + 37
3   QuartzCore                          0x0106914e _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 290
4   QuartzCore                          0x010692a9 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 68
5   QuartzCore                          0x010699af -[CALayer setFrame:] + 799
6   UIKit                               0x0126329c -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 302
7   UIKit                               0x01361d50 -[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] + 210
8   UIKit                               0x01361fae -[UIImageView setFrame:] + 63
9   SampleApp                              0x0001d331 -[YHAnimatedCircleView drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:] + 1329
10  MapKit                              0x00c1b8ff __43-[MKOverlayView overlay:drawKey:inContext:]_block_invoke + 847
11  MapKit                              0x00c1b572 -[MKOverlayView overlay:drawKey:inContext:] + 268
12  VectorKit                           0x0bff941d -[VKRasterOverlay drawKey:inContext:] + 61
13  VectorKit                           0x0bff75e5 __40-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource _queueDraw:]_block_invoke + 485
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0647d818 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x064924b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what your Framework is doing but the drawing of layers shouldn't be done in the main thread. So like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956149/adding-mkpolyline-overlay-to-mkmapview-crashes-application) thread discussed and solved, you should just use an async-dispatcher.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_mapView addOverlay:circle];
    });
```

Comment: I've tried to adopt your solution but it doesn't change anything, I get the same error as above "CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction".

Comment: Ok. maybe you did not get all relevant parts of your code dispatched. See also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507193/coreanimation-warning-deleted-thread-with-uncommitted-catransaction).

Comment: Thanks, no way. I've tried  to dispatch all the overlay drawing on the main queue but I got no results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that updated the YickHong solution for iOS7.

https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay

In iOS7, you can no longer add subviews to an MKOverlay. Check out the code here and ping me if you have any questions jeff@energ.io.