# Adding MKPolyline Overlay to MKMapView crashes application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

My application was working fine on iOS6 but it is crashing on iOS 7 due to bad access when I add overlay to MKMapView.My code is as follows

```
MKPolyline *polyline = [[MKPolyline alloc] init];
   polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
    [directionMap addOverlay:polyline];
```

[image]

This is the crash log
(lldb) bt
*

```
 thread #51: tid = 0x1cc5, 0x38755f8c libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_retain$VARIANT$mp + 8, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x38755f8c libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_retain$VARIANT$mp + 8
    frame #1: 0x3598dbc8 VectorKit`-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource init] + 176
    frame #2: 0x358cfd24 VectorKit`-[VKMapModel _rasterOverlayTileSourceForLevel:] + 308
    frame #3: 0x358d0226 VectorKit`-[VKMapModel addRasterOverlay:] + 46
    frame #4: 0x2f068dfe MapKit`-[MKOverlayContainerView _insertDrawable:forOverlay:atIndex:level:] + 1010
    frame #5: 0x2f06752e MapKit`-[MKOverlayContainerView _configureAndAddDrawable:forOverlay:level:] + 326
    frame #6: 0x2f0676ac MapKit`-[MKOverlayContainerView _considerAddingDrawable:inAddRect:level:] + 372
    frame #7: 0x2f067cce MapKit`-[MKOverlayContainerView addOverlay:level:] + 246
    frame #8: 0x001394c8 Falcon`-[GetDirectionVC showRouteFrom:to:](self=0x19742820, _cmd=0x001fa466, f=CLLocationCoordinate2D at 0x04f9ec2c, t=CLLocationCoordinate2D at 0x04f9ec1c) + 956 at GetDirectionVC.m:226
    frame #9: 0x001390ee Falcon`-[GetDirectionVC loadLocations](self=0x19742820, _cmd=0x001fa458) + 1314 at GetDirectionVC.m:173
    frame #10: 0x2e876e26 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1062
    frame #11: 0x38891c1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 140
    frame #12: 0x38891b8e libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 102
```

(lldb)

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: I have edited question with the crash log please check it.Thanks

Comment: Well, in the documentation nothing is change for MKpolyline, but viewForOverlay method has been deprecated in iOS7.0. Try using, - (MKOverlayRenderer *)rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay instead of viewForOverlay method.

Comment: Yea I am using new iOS 7 MKMapviewDelegate - (MKOverlayRenderer *) but I don't know why I am getting bad access crash :(

Comment: Why are you doing alloc/init for MKpolyline object? polylineWithCoordinates method returns a MKPolyline object.

Comment: Yea earlier I was not doing alloc/init of MKPolyLine then I thought that may be fixed the bad access crash but it doesn't help either.

Comment: How is directionMap allocated? Make sure it is not getting deallocated. I agree it gets really frustrating when one thing works on previous version and doesnot on the newer one.

Comment: The directionMap is an IBOutlet of MKMapView and added in xib file.

Comment: Same here, my code worked fine until iOS 7, I'm working on this bug for hours, seems like Apple bug.

Comment: I am aso working on it since morning,don't have any clue why it is crashing with bad acess on addOverlay. If you find any fix then plz share here

Comment: Sure, I'll update here.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, the stack trace looks misleading to me. My bugfix is to explicitely add the overlay on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [mapView addOverlay:myRouteLine];
});
```

or if you'd like to use the new MKOverlayRenderer:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [mapView addOverlay:myRouteLine level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
});
```

In my case, I'm downloading asynchronously some data, generate Polylines, create MKOverlayViews / MKOverlayRenderes (didn't help to replace the deprecated code) and add the overlay to the map.

Comment: Thank you !! I have been looking for a solution for days, as you said, the method crashes on background threads in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Use following If you are creating poly lines in thread other than main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addPolyLineToMap:) withObject:polyline waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)addPolyLineToMap:(MKPolyline*)apolyline{
    [mapview addOverlay:apolyline];
}
```