# Passing variable to other method using performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: ios, objective-c

These are two methods I have:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString   *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress

{
NSLog(@"RECEIVING... %@ from peer: %@", progress, peerID);
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithPeerId:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void) updateUIWithPeerId:(MCPeerID *)peerID {

UIProgressView *progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 20);
progressBar.progress = 0.5;
//UIButton* btn = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary objectForKey:peerID];
[self.view addSubview:progressBar];

UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert View Title" message:@"Alert View Text" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alertView show];
}
```

The first calls the second with this code:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithPeerId:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But I want to pass on to the second method this variable: peerID. Usually I would do:

```
[self updateUIWithPeerId: peerID];
```

but I can't do it in `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithPeerId:)
                       withObject:peerID
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thread withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`
>
> ...
>
> *arg*
> The argument to pass to the method when it is invoked. Pass `nil` if the method does not take an argument.

---

Alternatively

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self updateUIWithPeerId:peerID];
}
```

but be absolutely sure not to invoke this from the main queue, since calling `dispatch_sync` on the current queue will result in a deadlock.

Some insights about the slight difference between the two approaches can be found here: [Whats the difference between performSelectorOnMainThread and dispatch_async on main queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335434/whats-the-difference-between-performselectoronmainthread-and-dispatch-async-on-m)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Should I do - (void)performSelector:updateUIWithPeerId onThread:(NSThread *)thread withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait if I am thinking to use the method [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithPeerId:)
                       withObject:peerID
                    waitUntilDone:YES]; more than once in my code?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: Whenever I call the code you provided me it will result in the void method - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thread withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait. The point is that it might be a different method e.g. instead of updateUIWithPeerId, it might be updateUIWithPeerId2. How do I differentiate between the two within the void method?

Comment: I'm frankly not following. What you do you mean by *within* the void method? What's your use case?