# iOS: how to properly stop an Activity Indicator?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, uiactivityindicatorview, nsthread

I'd like to stop the animation of the indicator within a method called by default NSNotificationCenter with a postNotificationName.
So I'm doing this on Main Thread

```
-(void)method
{
    ...
    [ind performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

It does'n work. Method is called correctly, any other called selectors do their job but not stopAnimating.
I put [ind stopAnimating] in another function and then called it via performSelectorOnMainThread but it still didn't worked.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9336253/986169. It might help

Comment: Make sure you try to stop it after you start it. :) 
In a multithreaded environment this is an important stuff.

Comment: very good hints in that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the below method which starts and stops the activity indicator on main thread in a single method, also provides you to execute your code asynchronously as well-

```
- (void)showIndicatorAndStartWork
{
    // start the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue)
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do your background code here

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // stop the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue again)  
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

Create a method that stops your animation

```
-(void)stopAnimationForActivityIndicator
{
    [ind stopAnimating];
}
```

Replace your method like this -

```
-(void)method
{
    ...
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimationForActivityIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Should do the magic...

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
-(void)method
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
       [ind stopAnimating];   
    });
}
```