# performSelectorOnMainThread with performSegue

Tags: multithreading, swift, segue

I have been looking for an answer for this for a while now, but have not yet found any. I have a method that looks like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowNextView", sender: nil)
}
```

Is it possible in some way to use the `performSelectorOnMainThread` for this purpose? As I can see `performSelectorOnMainThread` on accepts one parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335434/whats-the-difference-between-performselectoronmainthread-and-dispatch-async-on-m

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use performSelectorOnMainThread?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the sender to self instead of nil?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowNextView",sender: self)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
   let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowNextView", sender: nil)
                }
            }
```